# How do Threads differ from Asynchronous code for I/O bound behaviour?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

In the context of Python where Threads are not run in parallel due to the python GIL, Threads are commonly used for I/O bound operations such as network requests to perform behaviour when a running Thread hits an operation to free the GIL. However, I have been reading that Asynchronous code should instead be used for I/O bound operations, where Asychronous code uses the event loop on a single thread.

Does one provide more benefits over another when used for the typical reccomended usage of I/O operations or concurrency? If I were to wait on a network request, waiting on a system operation for reading a file, should should someone use Threads vs Asychronous code?